# C++ How do I change the value of the original variable in a function?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, sfml

```
#include "box.h"

box::box()
{
    boxX= 50.0f;
    boxY= 50.0f;


    box.setSize(Vector2f(boxX, boxY));
    box.setFillColor(Color::Red);


}

box::~box()
{
}

void box::Update(RectangleShape plr)
{
    *boxXPtr= 550.0f;
    *boxYPtr= 550.0f;

    box.setSize(Vector2f(boxX, boxY));
}

void box::Draw(RenderWindow & window)
{

    window.draw(box);
}
```

The box being displayed is 50x50 even when the Update function executes. I thought the original value is changed when using a pointer to it, but the value is only changed within the function regardless.

```
#ifndef BOXP_H
#define BOXP_H
#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
class BoxP
{
public:
    BoxP();
    ~BoxP();

protected:
    RectangleShape box;

    float boxX;
    float boxY;

    float* boxXPtr= &texBoxX;
    float* boxYPtr= &texBoxY;
};

#endif
```

I included the .h of the base class and changed some stuff. Still have the same issue.

thanks for the help so far

Comment: Show your `box.h` file.

Comment: What are `textBoxX` and `texBoxY` ? Can you show the class declaration as well ? We need a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce the bug and help

Comment: Where are the `boxXPtr` and `boxYPtr` that `box::Update()` can see? And why does `Box`'s constructor create new local variables with the same names and immediately discard them?

Comment: It would be very useful if you could paste up the class declaration. My answer is *probably* correct, but the declaration will confirm it.

Comment: What's the reason for having `boxXPtr` when `&boxX` can be used anywhere it can be?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz using &boxX where boxXPtr is gives an error

Comment: @Mimi What error? (And are you really trying `*(&boxX)=...`? Why not just `boxX=...`?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz '=' cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *' and using  boxX= instead still won't change the value. I thought this was because it's a copy of the data within the function and using a pointer would would look at the original data

Comment: @Mimi If you got that error, you left off the `*`. If using `boxX=` doesn't change the value then your problem is something else entirely. Give us enough code to replicate that problem -- but you've made your code more complex, making the problem more obscure. (Whenever you have a problem with code, *always* give us the original code with no workarounds or repair attempts unless they definitely make the code the better. Logging and error checking is good, but obscure pointer work arounds are *bad*.)

Answer (score 4):

The two statements

```
float* boxXPtr= &texBoxX;
float* boxYPtr= &texBoxY;
```

cause new variables to be instantated, which are obviously *shadowing* the class members.

```
boxXPtr= &texBoxX;
boxYPtr= &texBoxY;
```

is the fix.

Comment: Setting the values in the init list is usually the real fix ;)